# SVN merge taking all changes from new repo

Tags: svn

I am having one stable trunk and one unstable trunk. 
Now if I modify any thing in unstable branch. 
I want to do merge it to trunk .

I want to take all the changes in the unstable trunk and commit to the trunk .

How can I dot that

if I fire a dry run like

svn merge svn:///ustable --dry-run

It is showing conflict for the folder which are not inside stable trunk.

Comment: I have a bit a problem to understand your current situation: You have 2 trunks (1 is normal in Subversion, the others are all called branches (if worked on) or tags (if frozen)); Do you want to work with the "unstable trunk" later on? Do you had a look at the chapter [Basic Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging) in the SVN Red Book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, anything is allowed in subversion but there are "best practices".

trunk, branch and tags are just naming conventions, you can have your files where ever you like, even several trunks. What is important to get merging to work is that you do `svn copy` when you do a new branch and that you commit all directories and files when you do merge.

So from your question I figure you have once done a `svn copy svn://host/trunk svn://host/unstable_trunk`. That is fine although not really normal best practice.

Now, when ever you want to have changes from trunk down to unstable_trunk you would issue a 'svn merge ^/trunk' standing inside your unstable_trunk working copy. Once you resolved the conflicts you do `svn commit -m'merged changes from trunk'`. This will record a svn property callded svn:mergeinfo on all nodes affected so that future merges knows what is already merged. I find it best to make sure you do that commit on the root directory.

Also important is that you only do one re-integrate from the branch back to trunk.